# How to convert the elements of a matrix into a single vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a matrix as follows:

```
A= 1 2
   3 4
   5 6
   7 8
```

I want to arrange the elements of this matrix in such a way that it will give me the following output:

```
B= 1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
```

Any kind of suggestion will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the transpose of `A` and unroll it into a vector:

```
B = A.';
B = B(:);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
B = reshape(A.', [], 1);
```

The reason why you transpose the matrix `A` first is because MATLAB does the unrolling in **column-major** format, which means that the columns are traversed first.  You are trying to do this row-wise, and so you'd need to transpose the input to achieve the same effect.

Here's what the output looks like (using both):

```
>> A= [1 2
   3 4
   5 6
   7 8];
>> B = A.';
>> B = B(:);
>> B

B =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
```

Also:

```
>> A= [1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8];
>> B = reshape(A.', [], 1)

B =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
```